# Is there a way to search users of application via userId while using Identity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im just curious if there is a technique to search for users of the application using their userId. Im using asp.net mvc with authentication enabled.I want to do the same thing that stackoveflow does when you visit your personal page example stackoverflow_.com/users/7416543/username Im not sure what they do here but it seems they have a usersController with a userId. I can Do this from scratch by just building my own models,controllers and views with no authentication enabled but is there a way to incorporate identityUsers(applicationUsers Class). It seems to have its own system thats very obtrusive when trying to pull data out of its tables like aspNetUsers.Its been giving me a hard time.Im just curious if I would have to make another Usermodel and link the userId from aspNetusers with a foreign key on the new model. If anyone knows any way to accomplish this that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `UserManager<applicationUser>`:

```
var users = this.UserManager.Users
    .Where(p => p.UserId == "yourvalue")
    .ToList();
```

Comment: wow its almost been a year and I finally get what you were saying.